# Run binary on apache2

Tags: apache2

I have a CGI script which I am running on Apache 2. It consists of several external commands amongst which there is one `signalp` command:

```
./signalp -t -m mature.fsa -euk -f all input.fsa > output.fsa
```

Signalp is a perl script which utilizes FASTA.pm present in `/usr/local/bin/signalp-4.1/lib`, and the system architecture binary, I.e., `nnhowplayer.platform_architecture,`which for my system is `nnhowplayer.Linux_x86_64 and it is located in /usr/local/bin/signalp-4.1/bin`.

The problem is when I run this command on my system it works fine but whenever I try to run it on apache 2 server, it gives the following error:

```
File /usr/local/bin/signalp-4.1/bin/nnhowplayer. cannot be found.
```

Comment: Does `/usr/local/bin/signalp-4.1/bin/nnhowplayer` exist?

Answer (score 1):

Running the commands from the web isn't different from running them from the system.  The main culprit for discrepancies is environment **variables** and **paths**.

Test the variables and path between the two (running from the system and running from Apache2) and correct the discrepancy.

**You can check your Apache2 environment variables and paths with these steps:**

Create a simple script to show your environment:

`/usr/local/bin/set.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

set
```

**Run it on the web either using PHP or Perl:**

**Using Perl:**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

print "\n\n";

print system("/usr/local/bin/set.sh");
```

**Using PHP:**

```perl
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <pre>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; 
 system("/usr/local/bin/set.sh");
 ?> 
 </pre>
 </body>
</html>
```

The best place to start will be to make sure you have the paths from your login included in the path of the program running on Apache2.

In this case Apache2 is reporting this for the path:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

When running from the terminal I get this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

If you test adding all the path variables to your web instance while running the program, you should get the same results as you get when running it from the terminal.  After you have it running, you can systematically trim the path elements that you find are not needed, such as `/usr/games`, `/usr/local/games` and `/snap/bin`.

Comment: I tried running it using Perl, it says : No such file or directory :exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/set.cgi failed

Comment: How did you try to run the Perl script?  Just in case you had problems setting up Apache for running Perl scripts, I also provided a PHP example.  What did you get for the path when you run the PHP script from Apache2?

Comment: I think there is no problem with running perl scripts on apache because other scripts are running fine. I ran this script as cgi from cgi-bin folder and it gave the error mentioned above.

Comment: What method did you try to run the Perl script online?  What is the output of running the Perl script offline?  Since there aren't any special environment variables in the script, it should give the same output online that it gives offline.

Comment: I don't get what do you mean by method. I saved the perl file as set.cgi in my cgi-bin folder and set.pl, ran on apache and terminal respectively. But on running on apache it gives error while running fine on terminal.

Comment: Are you able to run any other Perl script on your system?  Are you able to run a Perl script that prints "Hello World."?

Comment: @user8392790 Can you give me the output of: `type set.sh`

Comment: Yes, other scripts are running fine.

Comment: Output: set.sh is /usr/local/bin/set.sh

Comment: I'm sure I can figure it out starting out with the exact output of `type set.sh`.  That is a command.  Would you mind typing it at the terminal and posting the output.  I know it's obvious to you, but my seeing the output will make it easier for me to get to the next step for resoving the issue.

Comment: I see you provided the output while I was typing.

Comment: Run this on the `set.cgi` file, then try the `set.cgi` from the web again. `dos2unix set.cgi` (You can install dos2unix with `sudo apt install dos2unix`.

Comment: Again, getting the same error even after converting it to Unix format.

Comment: When you say other scripts work fine, are you saying you can run a Perl `Hello world` script from the web in the same directory as the `set.cgi` script and it works fine?  Sorry if I'm asking something that you have already answered, but I'm trying to be clear on the discrepancy causing the error.  If I were having an error, I'd be doing the same checking and rechecking for something simple.

Comment: That's fine. I included the print {content-type: text/html in the file so it's printing the as same output as on terminal.

Comment: So the `set.cgi` that you are using is different from the one in my answer... Can you paste the one you are running in your question so that I can duplicate it on my system?  I already changed the `.pl` extension on my system to `.cgi` to match what you have.  I can't understand how a `Hello world` run without errors and the two lines of the example in the answer fails.  I was going to suggest adding this: `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);` just below `use strict`.  It'll give a web friendly output for the errors encountered.

Comment: If I could duplicate exactly what you are doing in the simplest way, fixing the difference would be the resolution to the issue.

Comment: **set.cgi**

`#!usr/local/bin/perl`

`use warnings;`
`use strict;`
`use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);`

`my $html = qq{Content-Type: text/html`
`Content-type: text/html`


`<HTML>`
`<HEAD>`
 `<TITLE>Test!</TITLE>`
`</HEAD>`

`<BODY>`
`print "\n\n";`

`my$out = `/usr/local/bin/set.sh`;`
`print $out;`

`</BODY></HTML>};`

`print $html;`

Comment: I can't get what you put in the comments to work on my system.  It might be the formatting... I can't tell the formatting you are using.  Can you past it to your question, so that I can get it exact.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77605/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-run-binary-on-apache2).